# What is the difference betwenn cvs checkout and cvs update

Tags: cvs, vcs-checkout

I have created a file, then with "cvs add file" added to the cvs repository and then commited with "cvs commit file".
Then I deleted the file locally with "rm file".
Then I wanted to restore the file from the cvs repository. I thought I needed to use "cvs checkout file", but this did not have the desired effect.
With "cvs update file" I finally reached my goal and the file was correctly restored.
Now my question: Why did that not work with "cvs checkout file"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cvs checkout` is for an initial local workspace creation, not for updating the files in an existing workspace.

Something like this probably works and illustrates the use of CVS checkout.

```
cd ..
cvs checkout repo/path/to/file
```

However, I would not really recommend that. Use `cvs update`.